# Unbounded operator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assume you have an operator $T : \operatorname{dom(T)}\rightarrow H$. Now we also know that $ran(T)$ is finite-dimensional. Does this imply that $T$ is bounded?( So is $T$ a bounded map $T \in L(dom(T),H)$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, unbounded linear functionals do exist.

Answer (score 1):

For example: ${\rm dom}(T)$ is the set of polynomials on $(-1,1)$ with sup norm, and $T(p) = p'(0)$ is the derivative.